# Need to make Anonymous user create node through a Form but can't

Tags: forms, users

I need to make anonymous user create a node through my site. The node which is create would be unpublished, which an admin can publish later.

I wrote the following code which works perfectly but the only gripe is that Anonymous can't submit it.

I also gave the permission in the Permission - Node: Create new content but nothing works ...

Any Idea please ....

### This is what I did:-

```
<?php 
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

                  //Core Form Elements.
                  $employee_name = $_POST["EName"];
                  $role          = $_POST["Role"];
                  $office        = $_POST["Office"];
                  $location      = $_POST["Location"];




                  $my_node = new stdClass();
                  $my_node->type = "my-node-type"; 
                  node_object_prepare($my_node); 


                  $my_node->title    = $title;
                  $my_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled

                  $my_node->field_employee_name[$my_node->language][0]['value']    = $employee_name;
                  $my_node->field_employee_role[$my_node->language][0]['value']    = $role;
                  $my_node->field_office[$my_node->language][0]['value']           = $office;
                  $my_node->field_location[$my_node->language][0]['value']         = $location;

                   $my_node->uid = $user -> uid; 

                  $my_node->body[$my_node->language][0]['value']   = $story;
                  $my_node->body[$my_node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';


                  $path = './sites/default/files/animage.png';





                  $path = 'node_created_on' . date('YmdHis');
                  $my_node->path = array('alias' => $path);

                  if($my_node = node_submit($my_node)) { 

                      node_save($my_node);
                      echo "<h2> Thank you, Node Recieved.</h2>";
                      echo "Node with nid " . $my_node->nid . " saved!\n";

                  }
              }

              else {

              ?>
                <p><?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'body', array('label'=>'hidden'))); ?></p>

                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="node_submission" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">

                  <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="EName" id="employee_name" value="<?php echo $user -> name; ?>" placeholder="Full Name" required />

                  <label for="Role">Role:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="Role" id="role" value="" placeholder="Your Role in the Firm" required/>

                  <label for="Office">Office:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="Office" id="office" placeholder="Your Primary Office" required/>

                  <label for="Title"> Title</label>
                  <input type="text" name="Title" id="title" placeholder="A Concise Title to your Story"/>

                  <label for="Name">What's your description:</label>
                  <textarea type="text" name="Story" id="story" placehold="Your Amazing Story" required></textarea>



                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button btn btn-lg btn-primary" />
                  <input type="reset"  name="clear" value="Clear" class="clear-button btn btn-lg btn-secondary" />

                </form>
              <?php
              } ?>
```

Comment: Incorrect way of using Drupal. Please read next https://www.drupal.org/node/1702548 about forms. Read about https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922 for saving node programmatically.

Comment: I don't think it is recommended to give permission to anonymous to submit nodes without any email verification or any sort of filtering. Your server may get filled with spam nodes even if they are unpublished it will still remain in database.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement this as to follow the drupal standard to create a form and save the contents of the node on submit.

```
 function MYMODULE_menu() {

        $items['Demo'] = array(
            'title' => 'Demo',
            'description' => 'Example form',
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('user_detail_form'),
            'access callback' => TRUE,
        );

return $items;

}

function user_detail_form(){

 $form['employee_name']= array(
      '#title' => 'Employee Name :',
      '#type'  => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Full Name'), 
     );

     $form['role']= array(
      '#title' => 'Role',
      '#type'  => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Your Role in the Firm'), 
     );
 $form['office']= array(
      '#title' => 'Office',
      '#type'  => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Your Primary Office'),   
     );
 $form['title']= array(
      '#title' => 'Title',
      '#type'  => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'A Concise Title to your Story'), 
     );
 $form['story']= array(
      '#title' => 'What's your description:',
      '#type'  => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Your Amazing Story'),    
     );
 $form['submit']= array(
      '#type'  => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Submit'
     );

return $form;

}

function user_detail_form_submit($form, $&form_state){

   global $user;
 $employee_name = $form_state['values']["employee_name"];
                  $role          = $form_state['values']["role"];
                  $office        = $form_state['values']["office"];
                  $location      = $form_state['values']["location"];

$my_node = new stdClass();
                  $my_node->type = "my-node-type"; 
                  node_object_prepare($my_node); 


                  $my_node->title    = $title;
                  $my_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled

                  $my_node->field_employee_name[$my_node->language][0]['value']    = $employee_name;
                  $my_node->field_employee_role[$my_node->language][0]['value']    = $role;
                  $my_node->field_office[$my_node->language][0]['value']           = $office;
                  $my_node->field_location[$my_node->language][0]['value']         = $location;

                   $my_node->uid = $user -> uid; 

                  $my_node->body[$my_node->language][0]['value']   = $story;
                  $my_node->body[$my_node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';


                  $path = './sites/default/files/animage.png';





                  $path = 'node_created_on' . date('YmdHis');
                  $my_node->path = array('alias' => $path);

                  if($my_node = node_submit($my_node)) { 

                      node_save($my_node);
                      echo "<h2> Thank you, Node Recieved.</h2>";
                      echo "Node with nid " . $my_node->nid . " saved!\n";

                  }


           //Add desired code to implement


}
```

For more information click [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390)

Hope it works for you!

Comment: you can check if user is anonymous and then set `$my_node->status=NODE_NOT_PUBLISHED`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for anonymous either. It works for all the other user types except anonymous ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new content type, with fields as per your requirement.
2. From content type edit page, uncheck the 'Published' option.[image]
3. From the permission page (/admin/people/permissions)
   Give the Anonymous User to permission : Create new content

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. But it doesn;t work.